# segmentation fault11: in this sort and search question

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

> **question:
> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.**
>
> solution -

- copy sums to cpy
- sort cpy in order to do binary search later on
- iterate cpy
- search for target - current_no.
- if present in cpy
- get indices in original vector nums
- append indices to result vector and return result vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        
        vector<int>cpy;
        vector<int>result(2);
        result[0] = 0;
        result[1] = 0;
        
        int indx = 0;
        for(indx = 0; indx < nums.size(); ++indx)
        {
            cpy[indx] = nums[indx];
        }
        
        // sorting to enable binary search on vector later on
        sort(cpy.begin(), cpy.end());
        
        
        int x, y;
        bool ispresent;
        vector<int>:: iterator base1;
        vector<int>:: iterator it2;
        base1 = nums.begin();
        
        for(indx = 0; indx < cpy.size(); ++indx)
        {
            x = cpy[indx];
            y = target - x;
            
            // sing bin search to make search time faster
            ispresent = binary_search(cpy.begin() + indx, cpy.end(), y);
            
            if(ispresent)
            {
                cout << "found" << endl;
                // fiding index of x, y in original vector nums
                result[0] = find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), x) - base1;
                result[1] = find(find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), x) + 1, nums.end(), y) - base1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> v(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    int target;
    cin >> target;

    Solution ob;

    vector<int>res = ob.twoSum(v, target);
    cout << res[0] << " " << res[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, only one pass is necessary to go through the list.  You also don't need to sort.  Think `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you are writing values to your `cpy` vector but it has zero size.

There's a very easy way to copy vectors just use `=`.

```
vector<int> cpy = nums;
```

That's all you need. You don't need the for loop that you wrote.

Comment: Side note: A debugger would have found the cause almost instantly. Run the program in the debugger. Wait for crash. Look at backtrace for clues. You're still stuck if you don't know you need to size the `vector` appropriately first, but at least you're closer.

Comment: yeah I had used gdb but had no idea that vector needed size first.